# remove validation constraint children Symfony2

Tags: symfony

i use FosCommentbundle, i have overload "comment" entity for add some property .

```
class Comment extends BaseComment implements SignedCommentInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    ...

    protected $newProperty;


}
```

now i would like remove the Validation constraint of Body NotBlank present in vendor into resources / config / validation.xml

```
 <property name="body">
            <constraint name="NotBlank">
                <option name="message">Please enter a message</option>
            </constraint>
</property>
```

because Comment is a children of baseComment i don't know how to remove this constraint